# Java 10 JavaFX SDK in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-8, efxclipse

im developing a new java fx project and thought it is a good idea to start with java 10 and later migrate to java 11.
My problem is now that i cant get the javafx css support in eclipse to work.
With Java 8 it was a problem of adding JavaFX SDK to the buildpath after installing e(fx)clipse.

But with the new module system this doesnt seem to work when i add JavaFX SDk as an module or an normal library to the buildpath. I still get unknown property warnings in my css and the JavaFX SDK doesnt appear in my file tree.

Im out of ideas and hoping for some clues to get this to work in eclipse with java 10.

Comment: Just FYI, when you do migrate to JDK 11, [JavaFX won't be in it](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3261066/java/javafx-will-be-removed-from-the-java-jdk.html)

Comment: Yeah, but i will be able to add it as an module then. I just dont get why my setup with java 10 (with javaFX still included) and E(fx)clipse doesnt work properly.

Comment: Just had the same problem: Resolved it by manually adding the following jar to the project's classpath:

    ...\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8_3.5.0.201907240300.jar